# Modifying Text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, text, modifier

I'm trying to setup a text modifier for my server, where if you type something like hello ~world~ it would italic the 'world' part. I want to do this in Javascript, but I have no idea about how I would go about doing this.

Basically here's how scripting looks for where I'm running my server off of.
This is also what I basically have done now, for this text modify script.

```
beforeChatMessage: function(src, message, chan) {
var user = sys.name(src);
var usercolor = sys.color(src)
if (message.toLowerCase().match("~")){
var italicmessage = message.replace(message, "<i>");
sys.sendHtmlAll("<font color="+usercolor+"><timestamp/> "+user+": "+italicmessage+"", channel);
return;
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, so,
I'm guessing the correct way to would be to use substrings?
Any help would be great.

Comment: can't you set up something like CKEditor or TinyMCE?

Comment: No haha, my server is basically running off of a game, where you can host your own servers. Each server can be setup with scripts.

Comment: type into where? a chatroom type thing? do you want it to appear italicised after hitting enter and having the text appear in the chatroom?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that with the `contenteditable="true"` attribute:

```
<div id="demo" contenteditable="true">Hello world!</div>

<script>
    demo.innerHTML = demo.innerHTML.replace("world", "<span style='font-style: italic'>world</span>");
</script>
```

[Refer to this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcko74mh/) to see it working.

Comment: This wouldn't work on what I'm running my server off of, basically its off a game application and they have their own variation of Javascript. Check my OP, I edited it with what I basically have done and what I mean so you can get more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to actually do this, I tested and it seems to be working.
Just using regex seems to work.
Example;

bold: /[b](.*?)[/b]/gi,